# how to handle iframes/frames dom in the iphone uiwebview

Tags: javascript, iphone, iframe, uiwebview, frame

in

(void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView*)webView

I inject some javascript to handle the iframes. e.g.

```
    stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
@"try {
    var document = window.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('frame'); 
    } catch (e) {
    alert (e.message);
    }"
```

It tells me the iframes document is undefined. Actually I have tried to print all the properties of contentWindow of iframe, but it's totally empty.

I know the webViewDidFinishLoad may be called several times for each frame load. But I can never get the iframe document.   I thought there should be at least once all the iframes are ready.

Could someone please tell me how to get the iframe document to process the dom in the uiwebview?

Thanks

Comment: After some test, I found that it's actually caused by javascript cross-domain limitation. The injected javascript is always in the top window, if the src of the iframe in this top window refers to another domain, you can't get any property in this iframe.

Then there is no way to process this iframe. Does someone have some way to access this iframe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use postMessage Api in order to access code inside cross domain iframe. 
Please see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for further details about how to implement this.